# performace issue with the code ,exponential working

Tags: java, performance, algorithm

I have two lists of type object with data , the first one is principal entity and the second is dependent entity.
In addition I have key table that relate between the principal and depended entity objects.
In the first for statement I get one instance of type object and then I go and loop on every instance of the second entity and trying to find
Match between them (i think exponential problem…) ,if match is find update the principal entity with the reference object .

The following code is **working** but I check it from performance perspective and it's not working in efficient way.

Do you have an idea/tips  how to improve this code from perforce aspect.

In the JVM monitor I found that `EntityDataCreator.getInstanceValue` have a problem.

**This is the method start**

```
// start with the principal entity
        for (Object principalEntityInstance : principalEntityInstances) {

            List<Object> genObject = null;
            Object refObject = createRefObj(dependentMultiplicity);
            // check entries in dependent entity
            for (Object dependentEntityInstance : toEntityInstances) {
                boolean matches = true;

                for (String[] prop : propertiesMappings) {

                    // Get properties related keys
                    String fromProp = prop[0];
                    String toProp = prop[1];

                    Object fromValue = EntityDataCreator.getInstanceValue(fromProp, principalEntityInstance);
                    Object toValue = EntityDataCreator.getInstanceValue(toProp, dependentEntityInstance);

                    if (fromValue != null && toValue != null) {
                        if (!fromValue.equals(toValue)) {

                            matches = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (matches) {
                    // all properties match
                    if (refObject instanceof List) {
                        genObject = (List<Object>) refObject;
                        genObject.add(dependentEntityInstance);
                        refObject = genObject;
                    } else {
                        refObject = dependentEntityInstance;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (refObject != null) {

                EntityDataCreator.createMemberValue(principalEntityInstance, navigationPropName, refObject);
            }
        }




public static Object getInstanceValue(String Property, Object EntityInstance) throws NoSuchFieldException,
            IllegalAccessException {

        Class<? extends Object> EntityObj = EntityInstance.getClass();
        Field Field = EntityObj.getDeclaredField(Property);
        Field.setAccessible(true);
        Object Value = Field.get(EntityInstance);
        Field.setAccessible(false);
        return Value;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you could introduce some form of Sorting into your lists and then not serach the complete dependent-entity-list, but start at an offset. Just a thought, not knowing the domain of your entities.

Comment: About code formatting: before pasting to SO, you should re-indent your code so that you do not use TABs, because, well, see above :). Your Editor/IDE should be able to convert tabs to spaces for you easily. And well formatted code is more likely to get a good answer, or answer faster, because some, who might otherwise answer, will just skip question with bad formatting and look for next question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my guess would be your best bet is to go through both lists once, prepare all data that you need in hashtables, then do one iteration. this way, your problem becomes N+M instead of N*M

---

edit

```
Map<String,List<Object>> principalMap = new HashMap<String,List<Object>>();

for (Object principalEntityInstance : principalEntityInstances) {
   List<String> keys = getKeysFor(principalEntityInstance);
   for(String key : keys) {
       List<Object> l = principalMap.get(key);
       if(l==null) {
           l = new ArrayList<Object>();
           principalMap.put(key,l);
       }
       l.add(principalEntityInstance);
   }
}
```

the do the same for dependentEntityInstance - this way, your searches will be much faster.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! when should I update principalMap and when do I create the match of the object?

Comment: it depends on how often the objects change. maybe you have to do it every time, but with the nested iteration you head, you were really going to have exponential timings. i don't completely understand what you're doing, but your matching is a string comparison. if you have two maps prepared, then you can get one side of your matching and get the other side (if any) by checking for that key in the map. this should be much faster than iterating over the entire list.

Comment: Thanks!I got your answer,one last question -in your example you build object  Map<String,List<Object>> principalMap = new HashMap<String,List<Object>>(); and in the string I need to put the key (I guess) but what happen if I have more than one key for every entity ,how should I build it?

Comment: List<String> keys = getKeysFor(principalEntityInstance);

Comment: oops. and then store in under multiple keys.

Comment: do you mean Map<List<String> ,List<Object>> principalMap ,if so how should i use it?

Comment: no, in order for this to work for looking up the principalObject for one key, you would have to add it multiple times to the map.

Comment: not sure that I got you for this point can you provide short example please?

Answer (score 1):

I might be misunderstanding your question, but I would suggest defining an equals method for your entities and a hashing method for them, so that you can leverage all the goodness that java already has for searching and matching entities already.

When at all possible rely on Java's infrastructure I think, Sun/Oracle spent a long time making it really fast.

Comment: Thanks but how should I do that?